# Como realizar uma GLM de uma variável com distribuição lognormal no R?

Tags: r, glm

Estou com o problema para definir uma "generalized linear model" com a distribuição lognormal. Simplesmente a função `glm` não aceita esta distribuição e vi a sugestão para se utiliza-se o seguinte comando:

```
 glm(y ~ a+b+c, family=gaussian(link="log"))
```

ou

```
 glm(log(y)~ a+b+c, family=gaussian)
```

Onde y tem distribuição lognormal.
Mas me questionei se está é a melhor função de ligação, pois aparece a seguinte mensagem de `erro glm.fit: algoritmo não convergiu` no primeiro caso.
Outra opção pacote gamlss, mas este ainda não explorei.

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Esse erro deve ter a ver com a existência de valores não positivos em `y`, para os quais `log` não está definido.